# What software should I use for HDR processing on Linux?

Tags: hdr, linux

So far, I've tried software like luminance, bracket and fotoxx. While bracket is very fast to make the openEXR images, luminance is good with tonemapping tools, but I'd like to try some more options. What do you guys use?

And in terms of options, how good are these programs compared to the ones in other platforms like photomatix?

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/20242/linux-software-for-creating-hdr-images

Comment: I recently started exploring fotoxx. Great results with minimal manipulations!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Hugin and panotools can be used to make HDR images.
Here is a nice tutorial from [Edu Perez](http://photoblog.edu-perez.com/2009/02/hdr-and-linux.html)
And here is a tutorial from the [panotools wiki](http://wiki.panotools.org/HDR_workflow_with_hugin)
I can't answer the comparison part of your question because I have not made those comparisons.

Comment: Ahh, I thought that Hugin could only create panroamas, but not. That tutorial is great! And now I've found out that you can even create HDR panoramas. I've sub-estimated Hugin. Great tool!

Comment: +1 hugin is a great open source tool for sticking, panoramas, and even HDR.

Comment: I'm playing with the hugin_hdrmerge's khan algorithm. Does anybody know what that algorithm exactly does?

Comment: s/sub-estimated/underestimated/

Comment: @JaredUpdike What is Perl doing on Photo.SE? :P

Answer (score 8):

I prefer contrast/exposure blending to “real” HDR. It gives similar effect without sacrificing the natural look of the image.

Use `enfuse` to run it from the command line. Hugin can run it too. digiKam has a plugin for exposure blending. See [Exposure blending with digiKam](http://scribblesandsnaps.wordpress.com/2010/05/25/exposure-blending-with-digikam/).

Comment: I've tried enfuse. It is great!

Answer (score 2):

Since I've learn some things from the time I asked this question, I'm gonna answer myself and show you a few examples.

I know, this is not HDR nor tone-mapped HDR photos, but I want to show you the great results you can get using exposure fusion.

Please, don't judge the photos, I just want to show you the differences in shadows/lights.

This is what I've done:

- Using the "hole scene" light metering, I changed the shutter speed till I got 0EV
- With shutter speed bracketing, I took 5 photos with stops of +/- 2EV (0, -2, +2, -4, +4)
- In my Arch Linux box, I used the enfuse tool and merge the 5 images to just 1.

These are some results:

- First photo of the serie 1: http://goo.gl/BYbt
- Final enfused image from serie 1: http://goo.gl/BlXU
- First photo of the serie 2: http://goo.gl/W2mY
- Final enfused image from serie 2: http://goo.gl/vsRj

Comment: Very effective, well done.

Comment: Links are broken.

Answer (score 1):

I enjoy using Luminace-HDR:

- Nice GUI
- good use of Exif
- allows you to continue if Exif data is missing
- takes advantage of Hugin tools

Comment: I was about to answer QtPFSGui, then I realised that they changed the name xD

Comment: When I briefly tried it, I had the impression tat Luminance HDR is more about achieving that special effect look than approximating how the human eye perceives a high contrast scene.  Did you use it successfully to create realistic looking photos, or do you only use it for the 'effect'?

Comment: I'm trying for exposure compensation instead of effect. I honestly haven't finished my first successful project in it yet because I picked out some...pretty bad photos to start with, sorry. I do like the interface and my first impressions of it, though.